# Installing Subclipse 1.6.x on MyEclipse 7.5

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, myeclipse

I'm trying to install Subclipse 1.6.x on MyEclipse 7.5, could someone confirm there is absolutely no way to do this ?

I've tried install via :

1. http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/
2. local site installation after download from http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240
   and
3. put the "plugins" and "features" directory downloaded in step 2 directly in MyEclipse "dropins" folder

   - for 1., MyEclipse says "No repository found at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/"
   - for 2., MyEclipse says "No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4/" and "No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede/"
   - for 3., installation fails at MyEclipse startup

When I access these URL via any browser, I can see these URL are valid and not filtered by firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If upgrading MyEclipse is an option for you, this is very simple.
1) upgrade to MyEclipse 10.5
2) look up Subclipse in the Configuration Center's "Software" tab
3) Follow the prompts to install Subclipse

Comment: I know it works for MyEclipse 10.5 but I had to use MyEclipse 7.5 on historical projects

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to uncheck the option to contact all sites during the process?  Also, if your browser uses a proxy server you would still need to configure the proxy in Eclipse preferences.  That might explain why Eclipse cannot reach any of the sites but your browser can.

With your option 2 and the option to contact all sites unchecked, you should not need any network access.

Answer (score 0):

With option 2, I assume you mean you've tried the archived update site. With this, you should be able to ignore the errors (which I don't think are related to subclipse but perhaps to updates that have been detected for eclipse). Just go ahead and continue the install of subclipse and this should install it successfully.

As others have said, upgrading to MyEclipse 10.5 (with 10.6 due for release shortly), is the best option. Your license allows you to install all releases, while your license is valid.